# How mysql database work flow in real time or in search request?

Tags: mysql

I would like to have a question that I am facing a condition where I have to bring the result based on search query parameter and I have to implement paging in it too.

Let suppose a search string has **PEPSI**

I am querying it as below

```
Select * from product where product_title Like '%pepsi%' LIMIT 0,100
```

The table products have 50 million rows.

So, my question is that how MySQL will work? Is MySQL go through all the 50 million rows against the keyword PEPSI in the product table? If this is the case the query will be very slow and will take many minutes even I add pagination offset?

Comment: Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)

Comment: `LIKE %...%` will not be able to use Indexing. You may look into implementing [Full Text Search](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx) instead.

Comment: `Limit` clause would ensure that query will stop scanning further rows as soon as it finds 100 rows which have **pepsi** substring in them

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thank you for highlighting this. But, I have just 3 fields in my table  id, product_title, product_description and I require all these columns thats why I used * here :)

Comment: It should not matter; whether it is just 3 or 300. Please read the link - there are various reasons to stop using `Select *`

Answer (score 0):

> Is MySQL go through all the 50 million rows against the keyword PEPSI in the product 
>   table?

Yes, though depending on settings it may block on the network side. That said, why should it work more than 100 hits? You ask for 0-100, so after 100 hits it is over.

> If this is the case the query will be very slow and will take many minutes even I add 
>   pagination offset?

Yes, On a 30 year old computer. On a modern machine, sorry, 50 million rows are SMALL. A handfull of seconds sounds more like it. Oh, and it stops after the first 100 results, obviously. Even 100000 results is small. Please, put some decent modern machine there with SSD storage and see thigns fly.

Answer (score 0):

- First optimization you can do is avoid using `Select *`. It fetches more columns (data) than required, hence blocking the network. Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)
- `LIKE '%...%'` will not be able to use Indexing (`Like '..%'` can use the indexing though). You may look into implementing [Full Text Search](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx) instead.
- `Limit` clause would ensure that query will stop scanning further rows as soon as it finds 100 rows which have **pepsi** substring in them. So it won't be that slow.